# media queries for tablet and phone

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hi am using 2 media queries and they don't appear to work when viewed on tablet or phone, the original css still appears to override. i would like 2 blocks one under the other for tablet and phone view rather than the inline side by side on desktop view

original

```
.site-logo {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 60%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
img.logo {
    height:auto; 
    width:auto; 
}
.header-search { 
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 40%; 
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top:2%;
}
```

media

```
/* Tablet */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .site-logo {
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    img.logo 
    {
        height:auto; 
        width:auto;
        margin: 0 auto; 
    }
    .header-search 
    { 
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

/* Mobile  */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) {
    .site-logo 
    {
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    img.logo 
    {
        height:auto; 
        width:auto;
        margin: 0 auto; 
    }
    .header-search { 
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

link to site: [Photohunters](http://www.photohungers.org)

Thank you
Melanie

---

### Update

Have tried again but no go!

```
.site-logo {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 60%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

img.logo {
    height:auto; 
    width:auto; 
}

.header-search { 
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 40%; 
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top:2%;
}
/* Tablet */
@media only screen and (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 800px) {
}

/* Mobile  */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 719px) {
    #sidebar { display:none; }
    #sidebar-profile { display:none; }
    #site-content-left {
        width: 95%;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .site-logo {
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    img.logo 
    {
        height:auto;
        width:auto; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
    }
    .header-search { 
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
/* Mobile - 320px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and  (max-width: 479px) {
    #sidebar {display:none;}
    #sidebar-profile {display:none;}
    #site-content-left {
        width: 95%;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .site-logo 
    {
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    img.logo 
    {
        height:auto; width:auto; margin: 0 auto; 
    }
    .header-search 
    { 
        display:block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

html as requested

```
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="site-logo"> <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"><img  class="logo" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ? >/images/logobestnewstreight300.png" alt="photohunters.org" /></a></div>
    <div class="header-search">
   <?php if (is_page('home')) { ?>
    <div class="fb-share-button" data-layout="button"><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href=" <?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" ></fb:like></div><?php } ?>

   <div class="headersearchbox"> 
   <?php $results_page = site_url().'/search-results/'; ?>
<form name="search" method="post" action="<?php echo $results_page; ?>">
```

`

Comment: do you have a `viewport` set on your pages?

Comment: I see that you have some nice effects of re-alignment of blocks when the page is resized. That tells me that JS is doing the realignment. Can you show us the relevant code that actually handles the re-alignment when resized?

Comment: Hi the only js. re-alignment is with the jQuery image grid megafolio that i am using, so it only re-aligns the images, nothing else.

Comment: Have tried again and still no go

Comment: Do you mind also posting your HTML? Try to simplify it if it's a lot to write without taking away from the overall content

Comment: But did you add the viewport in the <HEAD> of the page?

Comment: Managed to get it working - no idea how, rewrote the css and hey bingo, so may have been missing a closing bracket
thanks so much for all your help
Melanie